# PHPDocumentor, Netbeans & GraphViz

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

I configured my phpdpc.bat as  the following in netbeans:

```
C:\xampp\php\phpdoc.bat --sourcecode -o HTML:Smarty:default
```

I've found the information that I can build some how graphviz grafics with phpdocumentor but i did not get it running until now.

Which parameters / configuration do I need to build graphviz graphs with phpdocumentor?

Comment: I have found your question not constructive. Can someone help me?

Comment: Reading it now your totaly right ;) So I gonna formulate it more concret: Which parameters / configuration do I need to build graphviz graphs with phpdocumentor?

Comment: Please edit the question so that others see you edited it and can start to vote it for re-open if your edit actually adresses the issue properly why it was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your command syntax, you are using a 1.x version of phpDocumentor.  GraphViz usage is something new in the 2.x versions.  Doublecheck which version you are using, and upgrade to 2.x if you are specifically wanting graphs.  Also note that the old output templates of 1.x (e.g. HTML:Smarty:default) are not available in 2.x.  Examples of the 2.x templates can be seen at [1].

Also, if you do want to upgrade to 2.x, note that it requires PHP 5.3+, whereas 1.x requires 5.2-.

[1] -- http://phpdoc.org/templates

Comment: Oh man! That was the problem. Running the pear installer and everything works fine.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used GraphViz with PHPDoc (only separately), so I don't know for sure.  However, judging from [this blog post](http://www.haydnwilliams.com/blog/php-development-in-eclipse-on-mac-osx-lion) you don't really need any special parameters.  As long as GraphViz is installed on your system (make sure 'dot' command is running), you should be able to use it.

Also [this blog post](http://albertech.net/2012/06/phpdocumentor-graphviz-package-install-on-mac-osx/) mentions that once the GraphViz is installed, you should be able to see class inheritance in your documentation.

HTH.

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve my problem.

C:\xampp\htdocs\mir-dir>dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.28.0 (20110507.0327)

This is the dot version and the dot command is accessible but I get still no graph.

Comment: The inclusion of the graph in the rendered documentation might also depend on the template used.  Can you try to generate the documentation using a different template?  PHPDoc comes with a few, I think.